# How to Retrieving data from Mongodb with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to retrieve data from MongoDB with Angular but I don't really know how to since I'm quite new to this. I'm using node.js with an Express framework. I already have my MongoDB client and server running and using studio-3T for MongoDB as a GUI for mongo.

Here is the connection with mongodb in my app.js:

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err

  db.collection('loodgieters').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    else if (result.length) {
      result.render('loodgieters', {
        "loodgieters" : result
      });  
    }
    console.log(result);  
  });
});
```

In MongoDB, I have added a collection named "loodgieter".
key: hometext. value: this is some text

Now, I need to use angular to somehow access this collection and show the data in my HTML page

Anyone an idea?

Comment: what is the endpoint to get these values

Comment: You need to create api , a route function at node js and call the URl using $http from angular same as ajax call